# Do Bard and Rogue expertise stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, bard

If you multiclass correctly so you get expertise from both bard and rogue(e.g. Rogue 1 and Bard 3), and if in both classes you put the expertise into Deception, does it stack on an ability check?

Example:

The bard/rogue is proficient in Deception.  With a 16 (+3) charisma at level 4 would the character get a +15 bonus to Deception rolls?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [Do features that allow you to add twice your proficiency bonus, under some other name, stack with Expertise?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135832/do-features-that-allow-you-to-add-twice-your-proficiency-bonus-under-some-other)

Answer (score 38):

## No, they specifically do not stack

From the basic rules:

> Occasionally, your proficiency bonus might be multiplied or divided (doubled or halved, for example) before you apply it. For example, the rogue’s Expertise feature doubles the proficiency bonus for certain ability checks. **If a  circumstance suggests that your proficiency bonus applies more than once to the  same roll, you still add it only once and multiply or divide it only once.**

Emphasis mine.  Even if you somehow took proficiency in the same skill twice (I believe the wording in the official PHB always says choose *more* or *additional* skills), it wouldn't apply because you can't benefit from a proficiency bonus more than once.

Comment: @Loki If this solved your problem, or satisfactorily answered your question, please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer for this question. I m assuming that if you gained Expertise from Rogue and Bard. you could choose different skills correct? I.e you get expertise twice but you cannot apply the expertise bonus twice?

Comment: @MatthewPerryman Correct. With XGE and appropriate multi-classing, it's possible to get an absurd number of Expertise'd skills.

Comment: +1 Helped me with another question. But if you could update, you can actually take proficiency in the same skill twice, at least this is what I argue [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120688/43856). Obviously this is a non intended hole in multiclassing that they probably didn't notice.

Answer (score -2):

So, expertise doubles you proficiency bonus, not the stat modifiers themselves.
lets say you have a level 3 bard and you choose performance for one of your doubles, then when you perform, you get a +3 from your charisma (Ex.) and a +4 from your proficiency, which would normally be +2.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything beyond the existing (and much up-voted) answer. It's also not worded terribly well.